# Calling function with two different types of arguments in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ironpython

I am new to Python. I came across a weird case and am not able to figure out what the issue is. I have 2 versions of a function written in Python :-

v1 -

```
def fileLookUp(fixedPath, version):
    if version:
        targetFile="c:\\null\\patchedFile.txt"
    else:
        targetFile="c:\\null\\vulFile.txt"

#some more code follows
```

and v2 -

```
def fileLookUp(fixedPath, version):
    if version:
        print "ok"
    else:
        print "not ok"

#some more code follows
```

where the parameter fixedPath is a string that is entered and the parameter version is supposed to be an integer value. The 1st function (v1) does not work as expected, while tje second works perfectly. Both the times the function is called as `fileLookUp("c:\\dir\\dir\\", 1)`.

In the 1st case the error received is :-

```
fileLookUp("D:\\Celine\\assetSERV\\", 1)
Exception: fileLookUp() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Please let me know why is the 1st function throwing the exception?

Here is the actual code....

```
from System.IO import *;

def fileLookUp(fixedPath, version):
if version:
    targetFile="c:\\null\\patchedFile.txt";
else:
    targetFile="c:\\null\\vulFile.txt";
vulFileHandle=open(targetFile,"a+");
temp=fixedPath;
if not Directory.GetDirectories(fixedPath):
    files=Directory.GetFiles(fixedPath);
    for eachFile in files:
        print eachFile;
        hash = Tools.MD5(eachFile);
        print hash;
        vulFileHandle.write(eachFile+'\t'+hash+'\n');
else:
    directory=Directory.GetDirectories(fixedPath);
    for folder in directory:
        if vulFileHandle.closed:
            vulFileHandle=open(targetFile,"a+");
        fixedPath="";
        fixedPath+=folder;
        fixedPath+="\\";
        vulFileHandle.close();
        fileLookUp(fixedPath);
    filess=Directory.GetFiles(temp);
    for eachFilee in filess:
        if vulFileHandle.closed:
            vulFileHandle=open(targetFile,"a+");
        print eachFilee;
        hashh = Tools.MD5(eachFilee);
        print hashh;
        vulFileHandle.write(eachFilee+'\t'+hashh+'\n');
if not vulFileHandle.closed:
    vulFileHandle.close();
```

it is simply a recursive code to print out the hash of all files in a directory.

Comment: Fix code formatting, pls. Your variant will fail with ``IndentationError``.

Comment: Well i guess there is no indentation error as i have used Notepad++ to code it. So am pretty sure that the indentation is as required.

Comment: SO doesn't format tabs the same as spaces. I've edited, just awaiting peer review

Comment: if there were any indentation errors, an IndentationError should have been reported as said by @AlexeyKachayev, which is not the case.

Comment: Please show us the code that actually calls these functions and raises the error, and the full stacktrace. It's good practice to post a [full, short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: running this snippet works for me

Comment: i call these functions one at a time from the command line. And the rest of the code is really not dependent on this ...

Comment: Your function (in first case) just create local variable and exits. What does it mean "does not work as expected"? What result do you expect?

Comment: @AlexeyKachayev i understand that the 1st function simply assigns strings to a local variable. But the question is why am i getting the exception as shown above ?

Comment: @geek_ji The code you posted runs without an exception. If you don't post an example that actually shows your problem, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: ok guys i have posted the actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a call "fileLookUp(fixedPath);" around line 26 or so (just counted roughly) with only one argument sent in. Your definition doesn't allow that. Send in the version in this call, or give a default value to version in the definition.

Comment: oh... ok ok .. how silly of me... its the recursive call that's the source of the Exception. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way these functions are written, both of them must be called with two arguments. The error message you're getting indicates that one of them is being called with only one argument. In Python, if you want to make an argument optional, you have to explicitly state what value the optional argument should have if it is not provided. For example, since `version` is to be an `int`, and you test it with `if version:`, a good default value could be 0. You could also use `None`.

```
def fileLookUp(fixedPath, version=0):
    # etc.

def fileLookUp(fixedPath, version=None):
    # etc.
```

If 0 is a valid version number, and you want to test for whether a value was actually passed, use the second and test against `None` specifically:

```
def fileLookUp(fixedPath, version=None):
    if version is None:
        # etc.
```

Comment: but my second argument is not really optional. both the arguments are compulsory.

Comment: Well then, call it that way.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the (very badly formatted) full exemple, you're making a recursive call to `fileLookUp` *not* passing the `version` argument.